In SQL, how to search for rows by binary data prefix?
For example, I want to search for all rows that starts with \x00\xff\xaa in a binary data column. I am writing this pseudo-code in C# Entity Framework:
            IEnumerable<KeyValue> keyValues = Db.KeyValue
                .Where(kv => kv.Key.KeyBytes.Take(key.Length).SequenceEqual(key));

I know this should not work well. But is there any way I can search by binary prefix in any relational database or any ORM?

What would be the datatype of this column you want to search in ? And what database do you need this in ?

Please provide an example database structure with sample data, desired result set and actual result set. Please also mention the RDBMS of your example

In SQL Server you can do WHERE KeyBytes >= keyPrefix AND KeyBytes < theNextKeyPrefix

In MySQL you can use like 'yourprefix%'
Example:
CREATE TABLE t (c BINARY(10));

INSERT INTO t SET c = '\x00\xff\xaaa';
INSERT INTO t SET c = '\x01\xff\xaab';
INSERT INTO t SET c = '\x02\xff\xaac';
INSERT INTO t SET c = '\x00\xff\xaad';

select * from t where c like '\x00\xff\xaa%';

Result:
c
x00xffxaaa
x00xffxaad

Because b and c did not have that prefix.
Your ORM seems to be EF for .NET. If so, then you can use .StartsWith.
So, to put it into general terms:

in SQL, something like 'yourprefix%' should work
your ORM must have its own way to allow you to write code that translates code into the format explained above
use the ORM feature that's adequate for your ORM in order to translate your code and/or parameters into the proper like 'yourprefix%' format


SUBSTR and LENGTH is more compatible with all kinds of SQL databases and ORMs.
            IEnumerable<KeyValue> keyValues = Db.KeyValue
                .Where(kv => EF.Functions.Substr(kv.Key.KeyBytes, 1, key.Length).SequenceEqual(key));

